# Change properties from cell grid and refresh?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs7

I have a grid that when is clicked change the property cellwrap from false to true

```
    onCellClick: function(view, td, index, record, tr, rindex) {

        var
            me = this,
            vm = me.getViewModel(),
            field = me.lookupReference('descriptionField');
            
            field.cellWrap = true;
            field.getView().getStore().getSource().reload();            

    }
```

But i guess im making it wrong. Can i reload the grid with the cellwrap propertie change? Im using the v7.5.1.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cellWrap` is a [configuration](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-cellWrap) of an `Ext.grid.column.Column`. You can't simply change it after the grid is rendered, you need to use the `reconfigure` [method of Ext.grid.Panel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-reconfigure) to update the columns and set `cellWrap` to `true`.

You can try this code in a Sencha Fiddle (ExtJS 7.4.0 modern material), click anywhere and see how the top left cell is changing:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        const store = new Ext.data.Store({
            fields: ['name', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                name: 'Name1 Name1 Name1 Name1 Name1 Name1 Name1 Name1 Name1 Name1 Name1 Name1',
                phone: 111
            }, {
                name: 'Name2',
                phone: 222
            }, {
                name: 'Name3',
                phone: 333
            }, {
                name: 'Name4',
                phone: 444
            }, {
                name: 'Name5',
                phone: 555
            }]
        })

        const myGrid = Ext.create({
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            xtype: 'grid',
            store: store,
            selModel: 'cellmodel',
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                cellWrap: false
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }],
            listeners: {
                cellclick: function (table, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
                    myGrid.reconfigure(null, [{
                        text: 'Name',
                        dataIndex: 'name',
                        cellWrap: true
                    }, {
                        text: 'Phone',
                        dataIndex: 'phone'
                    }]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome.